# What is the 'hash' value used for in an App_Code.compiled file?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm poking around in an App_Code.compiled file that was generated when i published my website. It looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preserve resultType="6" virtualPath="/ProjectFolderName/App_Code/" hash="5b4133b" filehash="" flags="140000" assembly="App_Code" />
```

I'm wondering what the value for `hash` is used for?

Answer (score 1):

The hash value is used to disambiguate the file name, so the page can be compared to past compilations and inspected for changes.

'hash' is used to check the current page for changes, whereas 'filehash' is used to check any source files the page depends on.